# Tri-Parts Phrasal Verbs and Categories

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verbs, american-english, vocabulary

There seem to be three categories for tri-part phrasal verbs:

1. genuine non-separable (come up with);
2. flexible in that the final particle can be omitted (brush up (on);
3. mandatory separable (talk (.) out of).

Are there any that have been missed here?

Comment: You're not distinguishing transitive from intransitive, nor ones that allow Particle Shift from those that don't. Nor ones that are demonstrably prepositional phrases from those that aren't. It's not just a matter of how many words there are; these things are not linear.

Comment: You have not answered the question clearly at all. Sorry, I specifically asked about tri-part phrasal verbs and not about bi-parts or other forms. There is no need to discuss transitives or intransitives, I merely asked about the categories for tri-parts. These three are most common, but are there more? That is the question. Cheers!

Comment: John is (I believe) saying that your classification is itself unhelpful - it would be far more logical to analyse MWVs (or at least the subset not containing what look like nouns, adjectives or second verbs) as a whole. For instance, we need to decide whether 'walk away from' is best treated as a three-orthographic-word lexeme (here, a MWV) or not, before we can go any deeper into analysis.

Comment: @PatrickT.Randolph: I was not trying to answer the question; comments are intended to clarify unclear questions before deciding whether they **can** be answered. You asked for other categories; I mentioned a few.

Comment: "Tri-part phrasal verbs" is not a standard category term, and could be used in a lot of different ways, depending on context and intention. Given lack of context, I, at least, am unclear on what counts as a "part", and how **you** define "phrasal verb".  For instance, is _go sit down_ a tri-part phrasal verb? If not, why not?  What are the constraints? And what kind of "separation" are we talking about here? Particle Shift? Adverbs? Indirect objects?

Comment: @PATRICK T. RANDOLPH : There are four types of phrasal verbs: 1) Intransitive 2) Non seperable transitive 3) Optionally seperable transitive 4) Obligatory seperable transitive. So, which of these are tri part?

Comment: John and others are correct that there is no such classification of phrasal verbs as *tri-parts.* Whether or not the phrasal verb is separable depends on the verb being transitive or intransitive. And even then, not all transitive phrasal verbs are separable. Phrasal verbs are such a broad category that they are impossible to chronicle/classify in this format. There are hundreds of phrasal verbs that could be divided into several categories.

Comment: What is the basis for the assumption 'There seem to be **three categories** (of separability) for tri-part phrasal verbs'? Can you expand the question?